# Add Facebook login and data Collection from pages in django(Social Auth)

Tags: django, facebook, ssl, oauth

I have used django-social-auth in my django application . Since Facebook has updated their policy about request url that it must be from https my django application has giving me this error :

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to
>   this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https:/

I have already installed ssl in my site and it worked fine with Twitter and google.In twitter i have given this callback URL :

> http://example.com/oauth/complete/twitter/

same goes with google, Facebook does not allow you to even add callback URL with http in it. Now I can not get pass through this. Is their any way to get go pass through it. Help needed .

I am in my  facebook app's settings > basics : 
I have

```
**App ID: XXXX , App secret :XXXX , 
Displayname: app1 , Namespace : oauth, 
App Domains: https://humbusy.tk , Contact Email : XXXX , 
Privacy policy :'XXXX',  TOS URL : 'XXXX'**
```

Answer (score 0):

your url must be https e.g, https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/

you can use to make http to  https 
(for localhost)https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver

Comment: I added them but same error is given . Link to my site https://humbusy.tk/account

Comment: have you add redirect url facebook  devloper redirect page?

Comment: yes i have added this in my Valid OAuth Redirect URIs :  https://humbusy.tk/oauth/complete/facebook/

Comment: what is your app domain and website in basic setting ?

Comment: https://humbusy.tk/account this is the link and i am little confused by your question , What do you mean by basic settings ?

Comment: you haven't configured right your app on facebook developer page .Remove all http link from your app setting.

Comment: 1.Go to Facebook developer page https://developers.facebook.com/ and login

2.Then select your app

3.Go to settings > basics

Comment: check out above i question i have given my basic settings in my facebook's app

Comment: there is also an option  of website box also.

Comment: There is no website box in basic settings.

Comment: you can search with crtl+f